# Activity Not Found Exception

Tags: android, manifest

I have sub-folders(packages) defined in an application, which has to be defined in Manifest file accordingly.
But after defining as per the conventions and as suggested by patrons in their posts, the application crashes. The error again in the logcat is 
"03-17 19:38:54.118: E/AndroidRuntime(558): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {in.co.avksons/prox_analysis.prox_main_scr}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

I tried to look in each file on the specifics of the package, but could not find the error.

What are the possible causes for not acknowledging the package definition in the manifest file.

Thanks

Comment: CTRL + CLick on your activity:name ="youractivty",in "" ,what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Manifest file? I have a feeling you are referencing your Activity incorrectly.

If for example you have an activity called TestActivity, and it was under the folder Activities, and your package name was com.test.app then you would reference your activity as follows:

```
com.test.app.Activities.TestActivity
```

You cant use '/' in the manifest file, use '.' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have wrong declaration of activiy in Manifest. If you have package "com.application.view", for example, declaration will be like this:

```
android:name=".view.Activity"
```

Comment: Found the error and a way to handle it. In case the application consist of multiple packages, its better to define the class it in the root package, declare the same in manifest file. Once declared and acknowledged the class may be selected and dragged to the respective package. The manifest file will track and change the package automatically in ecllipse.